# Is there a word for the class of words used to describe relationships between people?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a way of describing the class of words such as brother, friend, enemy, predecessor, tenant, colleague which describe one person in relation to another, and might be preceded by my, your , his etc.

This would not include word such as idiot, farmer, composer, birdwatcher, author.

It would include words such as teacher in the context "she took an apple for her teacher" but not in the context "Mr Brain is an excellent teacher".

Is there a word or phrase for this?

I want to use it in the phrase:

> The Hebrew word "ebed", meaning "servant" is a  _________ word. It does not mean servant in the sense of a person doing a particular type of job, it means a servant in relation to his master.

Comment: Any reason not to simply use "relationship"?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Well, that is a good suggestion, thank you.  I will put that at least for now.  I do have a vague recollection from school, though,  that there is an actual name for this class of words.

Comment: Are you thinking of [tag:kinship-terms]? Ordinarily, however, this label is only used for familial relationships.

Comment: @choster  I think that probably is what I was thinking of from school, but as you point out it does not include non-family. Thanks.

Comment: ... "servant" is a "social link" descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is for ***[relational](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/relational)***, which means:

> Concerning the way in which two or more people or things are connected.

In your example, there seems little need to encode the fact that the relation is one between people.

Further, I prefer ***relational expression*** over ***relational word*** in your context. The resultant sentence is:

> The Hebrew word "ebed", meaning "servant", is a *relational expression*. It does not mean servant in the sense of a person doing a particular type of job, it means a servant in relation to his master.

An alternative is to call it a ***relational noun***. Nouns like *brother*, *sister*, *mentor*, *co-author*, *enemy* and so on, are sometimes called this in linguistics literature (see [here](http://people.umass.edu/partee/docs/ParteeBorschev2003ArgMod.pdf) and [here](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P88-1004)).

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree that *relationship* should suffice, to avoid ambiguity, you may use ***interpersonal*** relationship.

Your example:

> The Hebrew word "ebed", meaning "servant" is an ***interpersonal
>   relationship*** word.

Wikipedia:

> An ***[interpersonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpersonal_relationship)*** relationship is a strong, deep, or close association
>   or acquaintance between two or more people that may range in duration
>   from brief to enduring.
>   This association may be based on inference,
>   love, solidarity, regular **business interactions**, or some other type of
>   social commitment.
>   Interpersonal relationships are formed in the
>   context of social, cultural and other influences. The context can vary
>   from family or kinship relations, friendship, marriage, **relations with
>   associates**, **work**, clubs, neighborhoods, and places of worship. They
>   may be regulated by law, custom, or mutual agreement, and are the
>   basis of social groups and society as a whole.

M-W:

> **[interpersonal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interpersonal)**
>   *adjective*
>   : relating to or involving relations between people : existing or happening between people